# Behaviour of the sum of a function of a random variable and its PDF

Tags: integration, statistics, definite-integrals

I have $\int_{R}^{\bar{v}}(R-c)f(v)dv$, where $f(v)$ is the pdf of $v\sim[\underline{v},\overline{v}]. $ I am trying to determine how this integral changes as $R$ changes. I understand that as $R$ changes the integral $\int_{R}^{\bar{v}}(R-c)dv$ does not change in value (as the dimensions of the square area change in opposite directions) but I am not sure how to use this to determine the behaviour of the integral with the PDF, above. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't $(R-c)$ a constant in terms of $v$? Can't you just put it outside the integral?

Comment: @vitamind Right. Yes. Thank you. So then as you decrease R the constant term decreases and the integral increases. How can one determine which of these countervailing forces prevails?